# How to fix: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'

Tags: python, python-3.x, configuration

I've looked at past threads but none of the solutions are working for me as far as I know. My code reads:

```
import smtplib
import config
EMAIL_ADDRESS = '***'
EMAIL_PASSWORD = '***'
                    
                    if re.search(pattern, body) is None:
                        def send_email(subject, msg):
                            try:
                                server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com:587')
                                server.ehlo()
                                server.starttls()
                                server.login(config.EMAIL_ADDRESS, config.EMAIL.PASSWORD)
                                message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(subject, msg)
                                server.sendmail(config.EMAIL_ADDRESS, '***@gmail.com', message)
                                server.quit()
                                print("email sent ツ")
```

Comment: There is no built-in module called `config`. Have you downloaded one?

Comment: Don't think so... haven't really downloaded anything. Following this tutorial: https://youtu.be/mP_Ln-Z9-XY

Comment: @Lecdi i just pasted my expanded code in case any info helps. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial you are watching tells you to create a file called `config.py`, and put the definitions of `EMAIL_ADDRESS` and `EMAIL_PASSWORD` in there. However, you seem to be putting these definitions in the same script as everything else.

This is OK, but if you are going to do this, you do not need to put `import config` at the top of your code. You also don't need to put `config.` before the names of the variables each time you reference them.

The working code looks like this:

```py
import smtplib

EMAIL_ADDRESS = "***"
EMAIL_ADDRESS2 = "***"
EMAIL_PASSWORD = "***"


def send_email(subject, msg):
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp-mail.outlook.com:587")
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)
        message = f"Subject: {subject}\n\n{msg}"
        server.sendmail(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_ADDRESS2, message)
        server.quit()
        print("email sent ツ")
    except:
        print("Email failed to send :(")
```

However, it is not really a good idea to put sensitive information like passwords in Python scripts, in case you share them with someone else, forgetting that you have done so.

The tutorial suggests creating a separate Python file called `config.py` to store this, but this is not actually the usual way it is done.

The usual method of hiding information is putting it in a file called `.env` in the same directory as the main script, and taking the information out of there in the code.

The `.env` file is used because it is the conventional way of storing environment variables.

If you want to do this (which is probably the best option), then here is what you have to do:

1. Create a file called `.env` in the same directory as your main script, and fill it out with the information as follows:

   ```
   EMAIL_ADDRESS=***
   EMAIL_ADDRESS2=***
   EMAIL_PASSWORD=***
   ```

   (Note that you do not need speech marks.)
2. Install the `dotenv` module using the following command:

   ```
   pip install python-dotenv
   ```
3. Modify your code to take values from the environment file instead of defining the variables in the script:

   ```py
   import smtplib
   import os
   from dotenv import load_dotenv

   load_dotenv()
   EMAIL_ADDRESS = os.getenv("EMAIL_ADDRESS")
   EMAIL_ADDRESS2 = os.getenv("EMAIL_ADDRESS2")
   EMAIL_PASSWORD = os.getenv("EMAIL_PASSWORD")


   def send_email(subject, msg):
       try:
           server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp-mail.outlook.com:587")
           server.ehlo()
           server.starttls()
           server.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)
           message = f"Subject: {subject}\n\n{msg}"
           server.sendmail(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_ADDRESS2, message)
           server.quit()
           print("email sent ツ")
       except:
           print("Email failed to send :(")
   ```

To find out more information about `dotenv`, see [their official PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/#getting-started).